# JSF Back Link with Javascript

Tags: jsf

What is the best way to have a back link?

I tried the following:

```
<ice:commandLink onclick="history.back();">
       <ice:graphicImage value="/images/btn_back.gif" title="Back"/>
</ice:commandLink>
```

However, this doesnt seem to be exactly the same as clicking the back button on the browser. Specifically I get some problems with managed beans not being initialized when using the javascript back which doesnt happen if I use the browser back button.

(using jsf 1.2 with icefaces 1.8.3 in firefox).

Comment: It sounds like one is requesting the previous page, and the other is loading the previous page from cache.

Comment: The best way to have a back link is not to have a back link. It's a usability horror most sites stopped using a decade ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment about a back button.

Instead, save in the session the view id where the user came from (using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext())  and use:

session.get('previousView') in h:outputlink. (there is no reason to use a submit link for that)

Comment: can you provide some more details...not exactly sure what you mean.